# How to create access control on a record level on derived entities?

Tags: rest, api-design

I have a data model based around users. User owns records on several derived entities, e.g. A user have tasks and each task have documents. Documents don't have the User ID in their properties, only the task ID.

I want to allow users to read and update only their own documents via the /documents endpoints.

What is the security/permissions/access control model I should use for this scenario?

Comment: Assuming you have some sort of identity model where users log in, you simply check to see if the currently-logged in user owns the document before you allow them to retrieve or update it.

Comment: Since my data model is hierarchical there is no user_id field in the documents table (only in tasks). If I want to check this permission in real-time I have to run a query that joins the tasks and documents tables. If my model goes deeper I will need to join more tables. I want to check for permissions without running this query with multiple joins.

Comment: You can't.  Go ahead and run the query anyway.  That's what relational databases are for.

Comment: I can think of several ways I can implement this myself. For example, keeping a permissions table with user_id - object_id pairs. Other option is keeping the user_id on all tables. My question is if and where I can find a standard method to implement this. Something that is widely used, maybe a prepared library.

Comment: Most interesting programming problems are not covered by a library, design pattern or widely-used standard.  Were that the case, our jobs would be rather unremarkable.  The table with user-ids and object-ids is a good idea.  You don't need our permission; just put it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're facing an `Authorization` thing, rather than an access control. It's more like, even if an user it's allowed to create/read/update/delete a resource (access control), he should only be able to do that on their own (authorization).

This can be implemented with something as simple as a middleware that checks whether the user in session owns the resource (or the resource's parent). Depending on this check, you'd return either the resource with a `200`, or a `403`. In more technical words, you'd do a `if (session.user.id == task.user_id)` or `if (session.user.id == document.task.user_id)`.

If you're working with a MVC framework that supports middleware or pre-action lifecycle callback, you can do that in either. Otherwise you could use you're framework's event manager to do that check before the request arrives to the controller. Worst-case scenario, you put the check inside the controller's action.

Answer (score 0):

**The requirement**

I understand that you want to allow users to access/update their own documents, that is the documents related to the tasks they own:

```
    +----------+         +----------+         +----------+
    |          |        n|          |        n|          |
    |   User   |---------|   Task   |---------| Document |
    |          |1        |          |1        |          |
    +----------+         +----------+         +----------+
```

So to control access to asks, you need somehow to have an information about user ownership.  And same for document with tasks.

Note that there is a small ambiguity here:  are the task owned by a single user (yes: the ownerhsip can be stored with the task; no: the ownership has to be stored in a separate table) ?  And are documents related to a single task ?  But this doesn't change fundamentally the access control issue.

**Option 1: The document endpoint is handled on the same server than your task endpoint**

Implement the service to access the common database joining the relevant tables. Your RDBMS and its optimizer will handle this without pain.

**Option 2: You have independent microservices**

Implement some replication, so that every time ownership on a task is changed, the ownership information is propagated to the document service.  You could process update by update, or offer an API for periodic mass update.